# html 5 canvas: using draw image in game makes loop very slow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i am making a game based on draw images and clear it every some part of second.
i **started** with:

```
var peng = new Image();
```

and **then**:

```
  peng.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(peng, pengXPosition, pengYPosition, pengWidth, pengHight);
};
```

and in the **loop**:

```
var i=0;
function pengMoveRight(){ i++;if(i==1){peng.src = 'images/1.png';}else if(i==2)
       {peng.src = 'images/2.png';} else if(i==3){peng.src = 'images/3.png';}else if(i==4){
        peng.src = 'images/4.png';}else if(i==5){peng.src = 'images/5.png';}else if(i==6){
        peng.src = 'images/6.png';i-=6;}}
```

when i run it it works well on IE but on chrome and mozilla it`s too slow and the character is about to disappear .. i used setinterval(); once and window.requestAnimationFrame(); once and both of them cause the same problem.
what should i do to make it smooth move?
here is the full script http://mark-tec.com/custom%20game/

Comment: it`s smale about 200X300 px and my machine is good

Comment: Yeah,  I just realized you're making tons of server requests and that's what's slowing it down.

Comment: @ToBe Your browser has to load them in, though, which should only have to happen once.

Comment: and how should it be? , i created image opject then set the src and put drawImage in the loop and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the source, try to create several `Image` objects instead. That way, the `drawImage` call can always use a pre-loaded image.

Comment: i tried so , i created `Image` object and set `src='path/image.png'` and then in the loop put `context.drawImage(peng, pengXPosition, pengYPosition, pengWidth, pengHight);` and it didn't work ,i think i can't call `drawImage` after `src` because it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You need several images (i.e. peng1, peng2, etc). Could you add your test as an edit at the bottom of the question ?

Comment: @ToBe, first preload the images, one `Image` object per src, store those `Image` objects in an Array. Then, when all load events have fired, start your animation, where you call `drawImage(arrayOfImages[i] , x,y,w,h)`.

Comment: OK, and as @Kaiido said, it's better to use an array for storage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to preload all the images or use the sprite method (all images packed into a single sprite) in order to avoid the initial delay caused by the image loading only when it's needed.

However, after that initial problem, your example should run fine once all the images are cached.

Comment: No, the load event will fire slower than raf, the callback will always be stacked after the call and the animation will be messed up. Also, the context will have to load/parse each images each time. You should keep only the first part of this answer.

Comment: Yup, though the second one depends on the browser.

Comment: the second one in my comment? I think that's what specs ask to do, otherwise that would still be the same image being drawn. If it was the second part of your answer, it's just that the load event is asynchronous, thus it will always be called after whatever synchronous call is in the loop. i.e. if you do a `clearRect()`, your canvas will blink since the browser will have to render the drawing call first, then execute the asynchronous callback (drawImage).

Comment: I meant mine. Yup, agreed.